# Finding a set of edges to remove such that that the degree of each vertex is no more than K and the sum of edge weights is maximized

Tags: algorithm, graph, mathematical-optimization, linear-programming

I have an undirected graph with weights on each edge. I want to remove a set of edges such that each vertex has degree at most K, but I want to keep the maximum possible weighted sum of edges. I've come up with an integer program that should reach the correct solution.

My questions are:

- does this problem have a name? If so what is it?
- Is there a known polynomial time algorithm to solve this problem? So far I haven't been able to come up with any. Maybe I'm missing something obvious.

For funzies here is my integer program. Let me know if I made any mistakes:

```
# given (graph, K):
# Let x[e] be 1 if we keep an edge e and 0 if we cut it

# Keep the best set of edges for each node
maximize
    sum(d['weight'] * x[(u, v)]
        for u in graph.nodes()
        for v, d in graph.node[u].items())

# The degree of each node must be less than K
subject to
    all(
        sum(x[(u, v)] for v in graph.node[u]) <= K
        for u in graph.nodes()
    )
```

---

EDIT:

Thanks to the help from David Eisenstat I was able to find a good description of a polynomial time algorithm in Section 2 of

[Implementing Weighted b-Matching Algorithms: Towards a Flexible Software Design](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.41.8570&rep=rep1&type=pdf)  by Matthias Muller Hannemann and Alexander Schwartz published in WAE'98

This description generalizes the 1-matching case of the Blossom algorithm by Pulleyblank into the b-matching problem (which I also found be refered to as bidirectional flow).

Comment: The special case k=1 is maximum weight general matching, which is solvable in polynomial time. My intuition is that, if there's a polynomial time algorithm in general, then you can get it by solving the unweighted problem by generalizing the augmenting path lemma and then applying the primal dual framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently this is called the b-matching problem and is in fact solvable in polynomial time. See this cstheory answer: https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/17724/what-is-complexity-of-this-max-edge-subgraph-problem